# Need to Map keywords with user comments from 2 Bigquery tables using BQ SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two bigquery tables, 1 table has list of keywords and another table has user comments

*Table1:keyword*

| keyword |
| --- |
| love |
| hate |
| good |

*Table2:comment*

| userId | comment. |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | I love you |
| 156986 | #Love you too..... |
| 178986 | Good night |
| 179606 | Good stuff |
| 178606 | Hate you |
| 175636 | Don't spread hate☺️ |

Now I need output as:

| keyword | userId | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| love | 123456 | I love you |
| love | 156986 | #Love you too..... |
| hate | 178606 | Hate you |
| hate | 175636 | Don't spread hate☺️ |
| good | 178986 | Good night |
| good | 179606 | Good stuff |

I have tried below query but not working:

```
with A as(
    select keyword.keyword, comment.* 
    from comment
    left join keyword
    on replace(regexp_replace(lower(array_to_string(comment.comment, ":")), r'[^a-zA-Z]', " ")," and "," ") like lower(keyword.keyword)
)
select A.* from A
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you expect from array aggregation, I guess simple `like` and `%` suffices here. (If word boundaries should be respected, replace `like` by regexp usage.)

```sql
select k.keyword, c.userId, c.comment
from keyword k
join comment c on lower(c.comment) like '%' || lower(k.keyword) || '%'
```